# silverlight 4 {binding} generic dictionary to listbox (items not being displayed)

Tags: silverlight, binding, listbox

My xaml ...

```
<ListBox Margin="6,35,6,6" Name="lbLayers" SelectionMode="Extended"    >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key,Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value.Visible,Mode=TwoWay,StringFormat='Visible: {0}'}"  />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

.. and my code is ...

```
   void GameEvents_MapCreated(object sender, Zider.EventArgs.MapEventArgs e)
    {
        HookMapLayerEvents(false);
        this.map = e.Map;
        HookMapLayerEvents(true);
         this.lbLayers.ItemsSource = this.map.Layers;
    }
```

this.map.layers is a generic dictionary of type (string, MapLayer(Tile))

When I set ItemSource on the listbox there are no items in the dictionary to start with. When I click a button that is when I add a map layer to

```
this.map.Layers.Add("key", new MapLayer<Tile>());
```

Also MapLayer implements INotifyPropertyChanged for it's properties.

For the life of me I can't seem to get the items to be displayed in the listbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the value of `map.Layers` doesn't change nor does `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` implement the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface.  Hence there is no way for the `ListBox` to know that any new item is available to display.

If possible try change the `Layers` property so that it exposes a `ObservableCollection<T>` instead.

Of course that could be a problem if you must have a dictionary.  If you are only interested in ensuring Unique entries you could use a `HastSet` of the keys to manage that.  If you need the Key for look up then if there are few items a sequential search should do reasonably well.

A full blown solution might be to implement an `ObservableDictionary` that has both `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` and `INotifyCollectionChanged` interfaces.  There are a few about if you search for "ObservableDictionary Silverlight", just be careful that they actually implement the correct interfaces, its not good if its "observable" but not in a way compatable with `ItemsSource`.

Comment: After some more searching around I came across this article http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shimmy/archive/2010/12/26/observabledictionary-lt-tkey-tvalue-gt-c.aspx  I was setting ItemSource to a collection that did not implement a INotifyCollectionChanged interface.